# WMIC Process information doesn't get the status

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, process, wmic

Executing `wmic PROCESS get name,status` in an elevated command prompt in Windows 7 will get all running processes, but the status is empty (see screen shot).
[image]

How can I get the status of currently running processes through WMIC?

Comment: what status are you expecting to see?

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx , status is not implemented.

Comment: @sgmoore Howabout that....can you make your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-214721739) , status is not implemented.

> Status 
> Data type: 
> string Access type: 
> Read-only Qualifiers: MaxLen
>   (10) 
>   
>  This property is not implemented and does not get populated for
>   any instance of this class. It is always NULL.